# Copying syslog file to a new directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, directory, cp

I'm currently having an assignment to write a bash script that can perform backup log (syslog, dmesg and message) files to a new directory. I wrote my script like this:

```
cd /var/log 
sudo cp syslog Assignment
```

The file "Assignment" is in my home directory. When I used the "ls" command in my Assignment folder, I don't find a copy of syslog in there. Can someone tell me where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you'll do this that way `Assignment` file will be created in `/var/log/`. Try to use full paths for both - source and dest. file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean Assignment folder, not Assignment file.  Anyways if you cd to /var/log, then when you do a cp in /var/log it will think Assignment is local to /var/log.  If you do an ls in /var/log now you will see a copy of syslog called Assignment in /var/log.  To get syslog copied to the assignment folder in your home directory you need to specify the **absolute** path not the **relative** path.  Use the tilde, ~, to specify the home directory.  So your script should say

```
cd /var/log
sudo cp syslog ~/Assignment/
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help, that was exactly what I needed. Its working now. Once again thank you so much for the help. Now I can finally complete my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! [ $1 ] ; then
        echo "Usage:";
        echo $0 "<directory_where_to_save_logs>";
        return;
fi

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
  echo "Creating directory $1";
  mkdir $1;
fi

cp /var/log/syslog* $1
cp /var/log/dmesg* $1
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks for the help with that script, although I actually needed gms9rc's answer.